# Java foreach loop: for (Integer i : list) { ... }

Tags: java, iterator, foreach

When I use JDK5 like below

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
     for (Integer i : list) { 

      //cannot check if already reached last item

   }
```

on the other hand if I just use an `Iterator`

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (Iterator i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

          //i can check whether this is last item
          if(i.hasNextItem()){
          }

    }
```

How can I check if I've already reached last item with   `for (Integer i : list) {`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One way to do that is to use a counter:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
...
int size = list.size();
for (Integer i : list) { 
    ...
    if (--size == 0) {
        // Last item.
        ...
    }
}
```

*Edit*

Anyway, as Tom Hawtin said, it is sometimes better to use the "old" syntax when you need to get the current index information, by using a `for` loop or the `iterator`, as everything you win when using the Java5 syntax will be lost in the loop itself...

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    ...

    if (i == (list.size() - 1)) {
        // Last item...
    }
}
```

or

```
for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    ...

    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        // Last item...
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be !it.hasNext() to determine the last entry ?

Comment: And `i == list.size()-1` in the other example (iterators are generally easier to get right than indexes, although the syntax is a bit long-winded).

Comment: +1 for the first example - using a decrementing counter is very efficient

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes it's just better to use an iterator.

(Allegedly, "85%" of the requests for an index in the posh for loop is for implementing a `String` join method (which you can easily do without).)

Comment: Or which you can do with apache commons StringUtils.join ;)

Comment: phtrivier: If you are already dependent upon Apache Commons Lang. I wouldn't introduce a dependency just for that.

Comment: @Tom - There's still a good old join **hack** that works with for expressions: `String join = "x"; StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(); for(Integer i : x) buf.append(i).append(join); String result = buf.substring(0, buf.length() - join.length());`

Comment: Thomas: I prefer: `StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(); String sep = ""; for (Integer i : x) { buff.append(sep).append(i); sep = "x"; } String str = buff.toString();`. No hacky `substring`.

Comment: I also love that trick of changing the seperator after the first iteration. Simple and effective.

Comment: FYI, String.join() seems a likely candidate to be in JDK 7.

Answer (score 4):

The API does not support that directly. You can use the for(int i..) loop and **count** the elements or use **subLists(0, size - 1)** and handle the last element explicitly:

```
  if(x.isEmpty()) return;
  int last = x.size() - 1;
  for(Integer i : x.subList(0, last)) out.println(i);
  out.println("last " + x.get(last));
```

This is only useful if it does not introduce redundancy. It **performs better** than the counting version (after the subList overhead is amortized). (Just in case you cared after the boxing anyway).

Comment: Nice, but you should add a check that the list has at least one element (or potentially, is not empty).

Answer (score 3):

Another way, you can use a pass-through object to capture the last value and then do something with it:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer lastValue = null;
for (Integer i : list) {
    // do stuff
    lastValue = i;
}
// do stuff with last value
```

Comment: I think he wants to do specific treatment inside the loop when he reaches the last item, not getting the last integer of the list. For that, you can also do `list.get(list.size() - 1);`

Comment: I understand, however I'm showing here the general idea of capturing the last object. The question is a bit vague in that sense that he doesn't really say what he wants to do, just how he wants to do it.