# Pretty-print a Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, pretty-print

I am looking for a nice way to pretty-print a `Map`.

`map.toString()` gives me: `{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}`

I want more freedom in my map entry values and am looking for something more like this: `key1="value1", key2="value2", key3="value3"`

I wrote this little piece of code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, String> entry = iter.next();
    sb.append(entry.getKey());
    sb.append('=').append('"');
    sb.append(entry.getValue());
    sb.append('"');
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

But I am sure there is a more elegant and concise way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map to String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828252/map-to-string-in-java) because the format requested here and that of `System.out.println` are too close. And if you want something custom, this boils down to "how to iterate over a map in Java" which certainly has many other answers.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Or put your logic into a tidy little class.

```
public class PrettyPrintingMap<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> map;

    public PrettyPrintingMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K, V> entry = iter.next();
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append('=').append('"');
            sb.append(entry.getValue());
            sb.append('"');
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(',').append(' ');
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

System.out.println(new PrettyPrintingMap<String, String>(myMap));
```

Note: You can also put that logic into a utility method.

Comment: This is an antipattern imho. You add a strong constraint (inheritance) to your type, just for petty benefits (pretty printing). You would be better off using a regular map, but use a static method that takes it as an argument.

Comment: Although this is a working answer, while usually we should not re-invent the wheel if a solution from JDK or popular 3rd party lib already exists.

Answer (score 323):

```
Arrays.toString(map.entrySet().toArray())
```

Comment: Not so good if you have `Map<String, Map<String,double[]>>`, then you'll get this type of sting: `[test={test=[D@3995ebd8, 2=[D@26fa5067, 3=[D@1d956d37, 4=[D@2cead81, 5=[D@14934d2b}...]`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple tasks like this should not require an external dependency. As mentioned above, more complex maps don't benefit quite as easily from this.

Answer (score 76):

Have a look at the Guava library:

```
Joiner.MapJoiner mapJoiner = Joiner.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("=");
System.out.println(mapJoiner.join(map));
```

Answer (score 45):

Apache libraries to the rescue!

```
MapUtils.debugPrint(System.out, "myMap", map);
```

All you need Apache commons-collections library ([project link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/))

Maven users can add the library using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not handle arrays as map's values (eg. `Map<String, String[]>`). Only their className and hash is printed instead of actual values.

Comment: or log.debug("Map: {}", MapUtils.toProperties(map));

Comment: Also handy is MapUtils.verbosePrint, which will omit the class name after each value that debugPrint outputs.

Answer (score 31):

When I have `org.json.JSONObject` in the classpath, I do:

```
Map<String, Object> stats = ...;
System.out.println(new JSONObject(stats).toString(2));
```

(this beautifully indents lists, sets and maps which may be nested)

Comment: Man!! What are you doing down here? You should be top answer!

Comment: Warning: Does not preserve the order of keys for a LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 19):

Simple and easy. Welcome to the JSON world. Using [Google's Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
new Gson().toJson(map)
```

Example of map with 3 keys:

```
{"array":[null,"Some string"],"just string":"Yo","number":999}
```

Comment: You can also add nice indenting by adding the setPrettyPrinting() to a GsonBuilder:

    new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()

Answer (score 16):

Using Java 8 Streams:

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

String content = map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=\"" + e.getValue() + "\"")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: If you're going to necro a question, at least answer it correctly! You're missing the quotes around the value and it should be joined using `, `

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to convert the map to a JSON string it is:

- a standard
- human readable
- supported in editors like Sublime, VS Code,    with syntax
  highlighting, formatting and section hide/show
- supports JPath so editors can report exactly which part of the object
  you have navigated to
- supports nested complex types within the object

  ```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

  public static String getAsFormattedJsonString(Object object)
  {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      try
      {
          return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);
      }
      catch (JsonProcessingException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return "";
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the code for `HashMap#toString()` and `AbstractMap#toString()` in the OpenJDK sources:

```
class java.util.HashMap.Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
       public final String toString() {
           return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
       }
   }
 class java.util.AbstractMap<K,V> {
     public String toString() {
         Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
         if (! i.hasNext())
            return "{}";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('{');
        for (;;) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            sb.append(key   == this ? "(this Map)" : key);
            sb.append('=');
            sb.append(value == this ? "(this Map)" : value);
            if (! i.hasNext())
                return sb.append('}').toString();
            sb.append(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

So if the guys from OpenJDK did not find a more elegant way to do this, there is none :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do what you want by doing:

`System.out.println(map)` for example

As long as ALL your objects in the map have overiden the `toString` method you would see:
`{key1=value1, key2=value2}` in a meaningfull manner

If this is for your code, then overiding `toString` is a good habit and I suggest you go for that instead.

For your example where your objects are `String`s you should be fine without anything else.
I.e. `System.out.println(map)` would print exactly what you need without any extra code

Comment: his keys and values are strings; I think he got the toString method covered tbh.

Comment: You are right, but perhaps he copied a trivial example to make his point.But I update answer

Comment: Yes, I should have indicated that my map is Map<String,String>.
But I also indicated that I want more freedom in my entry values, for example having comma separated lists within an entry's value. So Map.toString() won't do.

Comment: Interface `java.util.Map` has no contract regarding `toString()`, so it's up to the actual `Map` implementation what `System.out.println(map)` -> `PrintStream.println(map)` -> `String.valueOf(map)` -> `map.toString()` will cause. It happens that the often-used `java.util.AbstractMap` provides a nice string representation for `toString()`. ... Other `Map` implementations may fall back to `Object.toString()`, which results in the not-so-informative `com.example.MyMap@4e8c0de`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void printMapV2 (Map <?, ?> map) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
    sb.append("{");
    for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (sb.length()>1) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue());
    }
    sb.append("}");
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map)` - as simple as this!

Result:

```
{"2019-07-04T03:00":1,"2019-07-04T04:00":1,"2019-07-04T01:00":1,"2019-07-04T02:00":1,"2019-07-04T13:00":1,"2019-07-04T06:00":1 ...}
```

P.S. add Jackson JSON to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Since java 8 there is easy way to do it with Lambda:

```
yourMap.keySet().forEach(key -> {
    Object obj = yourMap.get(key);
    System.out.println( obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this would be cleaner, and provide you with more flexibility with the output format (simply change template):

```
    String template = "%s=\"%s\",";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
        sb.append(String.format(template, e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // Ugly way to remove the last comma
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

I know having to remove the last comma is ugly, but I think it's cleaner than alternatives like the one [in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818729/java-foreach-loop-for-integer-i-list) or manually using an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty solution leveraging existing infrastructure, you can wrap your `uglyPrintedMap` into a `java.util.HashMap`, then use `toString()`.

```
uglyPrintedMap.toString(); // ugly
System.out.println( uglyPrintedMap ); // prints in an ugly manner

new HashMap<Object, Object>(jobDataMap).toString(); // pretty
System.out.println( new HashMap<Object, Object>(uglyPrintedMap) ); // prints in a pretty manner
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not answer exactly the question, but it is worth mentioning Lombodok `@ToString` [annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString). If you annotate with `@ToString` the `key / value` classes, then doing `System.out.println(map)` will return something meaningful.

It also works very well with maps-of-maps, for example: 
`Map<MyKeyClass, Map<String, MyValueClass>>` will be printed as

`{MyKeyClass(properties...)={string1=MyValuesClass(properties...), string2=MyValuesCalss(properties...),..},
 ...
}`