# How to print out hashmap store

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MainApp 
{
    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();  
    }

    public void start()
    {
        Airline airline1 = new Airline("AerLingus");
        PlaneStore planeStore = new PlaneStore("Aer Lingus");

        Flight p1 = new Flight("Aer Lingus","A01", 150.5, 10.5, 500, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);
        Flight p2 = new Flight("Aer Lingus","B01", 50.3, 1.5, 91, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.CORPORATE);
        Flight p3 = new Flight("Aer Lingus","C01", 12.2, -3.1, 56, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);


        Flight p4 = new Flight("Ryan Air","D01", 10.5, 1.5, 430, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.PRIVATE);
        Flight p5 = new Flight("Ryan Air","E01", 0.3, 2.1, 101, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.CORPORATE);
        Flight p6 = new Flight("Ryan Air","F01", 2.2, -3, 291, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);
        planeStore.add(p1);
        planeStore.add(p2);
        planeStore.add(p3);
        planeStore.print();

        airline1.add(planeStore);
        airline1.add(planeStore);
        airline1.add(planeStore);

        airline1.printPlane();
    }

}

import java.util.HashMap;


public class Airline 
{
    private String airlineName;
    private HashMap<String, PlaneStore> map;

    public Airline(String airlineName)
    {
        this.airlineName = "";
        map = new HashMap<String, PlaneStore>();
    }
    public void add(PlaneStore plane)
    {
        map.put(airlineName, plane);
    }
    public void remove(String flight)
    {
        map.remove(flight);
    }
    public void printPlane()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Flight List********");
        for (PlaneStore plane: map.values()) {
             //System.out.println(plane);
            // class
            // or:
            System.out.println(airlineName);
            System.out.println(plane.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

Hey i want to print out the plane store.  The plane store contains a hashmap of strings and flights.  That is where the flight.add/print come into the main app.  But i now want The airline and flights to print parallel so i put a airline store and im trying to print out the planeStore along with airline but all im getting is a memory address can anybody help me with this.

Comment: @Brian How do i override it ?

Comment: This could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10120273/422353

Comment: @Pendo826 as i showed below, add the method toString() to class PlainStore() or don't you have the source code of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get something like `MyClass@abcdef`, then you need to override `toString` in `MyClass` like so:

```
public class MyClass {

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "My class"; // Make a string here that you want to display
    }
}
```

So for example, if `PlaneStore` has `int planeCount` and `String name` for fields, then you can do something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Plane store | Name: " + name + ", planes: " + planeCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by:

```
System.out.println(map.toString());
```

which is the same as

```
System.out.println(map);
```

Then, to avoid the "memory adress" you mentioned:
add to PlainStore a method

```
public String toString() {
    return this.storeName; // or similar, 
}
```

This works because the Map can printout its content, by calling the `toString()` method of each key and value.

If this output is not nice enough, you must iterate for yourself:
Use the `map.entrySet()` and iterate over that.

Comment: I dont understand what would go in where storeName is.  I tried putting the map name but theres an error.

Comment: Each class shall have a toString() method: you want to output the map which contains PlainStore objects, so in PlainStore or any other class you want to print: add an toString() method which returns a String which represents the data of that class; Post the code of PlainStore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Apache ToStringBuilder class. But ofcourse toString() will also help. More information on [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/index.html)

Comment: use it quiet extensively, any tghts why u would not use it?

Comment: it prints all in one line, a list with 20 elements which each have 8 elements, is unusable to read. a custom read is always smarter

Answer (score 0):

Because you seem to be new to programming, I'm going to hand you he answer:

```
public class PlaneStore {

    private String name;
    ...

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```