# Why map's put method is not working directly in class?

Tags: java

```
public class Demo{
    Map<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
    test.put("A","A");
    System.out.println(test);

}
```

Why is the `put` function not allowed in this code?

Comment: You must put that code in a method.

Comment: last 2 lines do not compile unless you put them into instance method/constructor/instance initializer

Comment: you really shouldn't post questions like these on SO

Comment: Statements need to be inside a code block such as a method. You can't start a program without a `main` method.

Comment: please don't tell what should i ask on SO or not. i know that 2 lines are not going to compile but i want the reason behind that.

Comment: if you are not able to answer than just skip it instead of tell me what should i ask or not.

Comment: @MaulinPatel the reason is because you can't have bare code inside a class block. You need at least an inner block where code can be executed, e.g.: constructor, method, initializer block etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to run some code as part of object initialization, put it in curly braces:

```
public class Demo{
    Map<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();

    {   // This is now part of object initialization
        test.put("A","A");
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

`put`, or any other method call, is not allowed inside a class declaration section, because Java wouldn't know when to run this code. The language has specific rules about running executable code: it's either part of a method invocation, or an object or a class initialization.

The code in curly braces becomes part of object initialization. Any time that you run `Demo d = new Demo()` the `test` map would get `{"A", "A"}` inserted into it, and the map itself would be printed. Note that the printout is not going to be pretty. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10120273/335858) for details.

Comment: I know this 2 lines are not going to work but i just wanted to know that why it will not work.

Comment: Note: the OP will still need a main method somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Java works. If you want to achieve this `put` when class is loaded, you can try using a `static` block.

```
public class Demo{
    static Map<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
    static{
        test.put("A","A");
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

or if you want it to be initialized with every object creation, keep it in appropriate constructor or just a default execution block(similar to `static`, but without the `static` keyword).

```
public class Demo{
    Map<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public Demo(){
        test.put("A","A");
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first example won't compile as `test` is not static.

Comment: block of statement are not limited to `static` context. So you could have kept `Map test` as a instance variable

Comment: Well, there are two cases mentioned in the answer. First, initialize during class loading, and it is required to be static in such case. Otherwise, with object creation, in such case it can be instance variable and get initialized in default block or appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To execute *something* in a class, you need to define a method in a class which itself holds *something*.

You did:
class -> *something*

Correct:
class -> method -> *something*

Comment: this thing i know that it need method to hold something, my main question is why is need method hold.?