# How to get my HashMap to print out to a file correctly

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm working on a project where I have a file that the program accesses to get information on different crimes from a range of years. It then needs to add up the crime based on the type and put it into a file. I have the first part down, it does access the file and adds up the crime amounts by type but when I open the file that is created, it's not printing out correctly and I can't seem to find what's wrong.

This is what prints out on the file:

> ¬í sr java.util.HashMapÚÁÃ`Ñ F 
>   loadFactorI     thresholdxp?@     w
>   t Violent Crimes Totalsr java.lang.Integerâ ¤÷‡8 I valuexr java.lang.Number†¬•”à‹  xp  ¤Mt Rapesq ~   jt 
>   Vehicle Theftsq ~  {™t Aggravated Assaultsq ~   kƒt Homicidesq ~   t Robberysq ~   N
>   t NonResidential Burglarysq ~   kÿt Residential Burglarysq ~   ã~t Property Crimes Totalsq ~  ïit Theftsq ~  :cx

With the system.out.println it prints:

> {Violent Crimes Total=42061, Rape=1898, Vehicle Theft=97177, Aggravated Assault=27523, Homicide=399, Robbery=19981, NonResidential Burglary=27647, Residential Burglary=58238, Property Crimes Total=454505, Theft=342627}

The system print out is what I'd like to show up in the file.

```
public class CSVReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\Cassie\\Desktop\\mod04_dataset.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

            br.readLine();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println(data[2] + " " + data[3]);

                if (map.containsKey(data[2])) {

                    Integer a = map.get(data[2]);
                    map.put(data[2], a + Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
                }

                else {
                    map.put(data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3]));

                }

              } 

              FileOutputStream f = new 
              FileOutputStream("hashmap.ser");  
              ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);          
              s.writeObject(map);
              System.out.println(map);
              s.close();
              f.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {       
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! `it's not printing out correctly` can you be more specific ? Can you give an example of expected/actual output ?

Comment: Exactly. Please post what is in the output file, what you expect, and also what the system.out.prinln gives. It seems to me that you only need to [pretty-print your map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120273/pretty-print-a-map-in-java/52218365)

Comment: I've added what I'm getting from the file and what I'd like it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `System.out.println(map);`, you see the result of `map.toString()`. If this is what you want to have in the file, you can do it like this :

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("hashmap.ser");  
f.write(map.toString().getBytes());
System.out.println(map);
f.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PrintWriter, cause nö you are outputting a binary Data